# How to install QtQuick.Controls 1.4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, qt5.5

I have installed the latest Qt 5.5.0, but there seems to be only QtQuick.Controls 1.0 and 1.1. I want to use `TreeView`, which is contained in the 1.4 version.

Comment: Thanks. Found on 3 different directories `~/Qt5.5.0/5.5/Src/qtquickcontrols/src/controls/TreeView.qml---
~/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TreeView.qml---
~/Qt5.5.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TreeView.qml` Which one should I add to the path? @VictorPolevoy

Comment: Wait... did you actually try to run an example that uses the 1.4 version of the controls?

Comment: Dude, there are so many examples, how do you know which one uses the 1.4 version. Whatever, I found one. Though qt creator keeps warning `TreeView` component is not found, it works. Thanks @Mitch

Answer (score 2):

You should already have it. Try to find the `TreeView.qml` by using locate `TreeView.qml`. Also, QtCreator or your IDE should have proper `QML_IMPORT_PATH` which is taken from environment. For example, my `QtCreator` does not have set proper paths so I use it with shell script which sets the path and runs `/usr/bin/qtcreator` after - this makes `QtCreator` to see new `QML` modules. I don't know is this a bug or just a ubuntu-package problem, but it worked for me only when I set the `QML_IMPORT_PATH` manually.

You say you have these paths:

> ~/Qt5.5.0/5.5/Src/qtquickcontrols/src/controls/TreeView.qml
>
> ~/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TreeView.qml
>
> ~/Qt5.5.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TreeView.qml

Looks like you installed it by downloading official installer from Qt's site. So, the first path is a sources path. Don't use it ever, it is only needed to be installed into correct directory after compiling Qt from sources and performing `make install`.

The third one is integrated with your `QtCreator` installation, but it seems it does not work for you.

I'd say, your choice is to use second path (`~/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/TreeView.qml`). It is usually installed automatically to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/` on *amd64* architecture and to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` for *i386* architecture.

So, create a script in `/usr/bin/`, call it `dev-qtcr` for example and put inside it:

```
#!/bin/bash

export QML_IMPORT_PATH=/home/user/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/qml
qtcreator
```

Be sure to change `/home/user` to your home directory.

Comment: So, I add `QML_IMPORT_PATH = /home/zen/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/qml` to my .pro file.  But that does't work. Where should I set the path variable?

Comment: @Zen This is also an environment variable. Set it to this path and run qtcreator after this in the same tty. I was not able to work with new qml components by just modifying `.pro` file too - that's why I made a shell script. I may give you details few hours later.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with qt creator. Setting the environment variable doesn't make a difference. I find that I can import the 1.4 version, though  qt creator keeps warning `TreeView` component is not found, it works.

Comment: @Zen I'll check this out this evening. Maybe it works the same way for me, I am not sure. I'll notify you asap.

Comment: @Zen god, had no time for this. Maybe **this** evening. Also, what if you use a qtcreator from `~/Qt5.5.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/` directory? Does it work okay in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to export `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` rather than `QML_IMPORT_PATH` ?

See [Import Statements | Qt QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html)

Comment: Qt creator still warns that `TreeView` is unknow.

Comment: You can try to define the QML2_IMPORT_PATH in the project configuration :
Project -> Build and Run -><YOUR_KIT> -> Run ->Run Environment -> Details -> Add
Add *QML2_IMPORT_PATH* and set the value to */home/zen/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/qml*

Comment: Have you built and installed Qt5.5 ?
If your setup is Ok, every thing should work out out the box.
Once Qt5.5 is installed, you have in QtCreator to add the freshly installed version and create a new kit. The configure your project to use the kit you have created for Qt5.5.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later. BTW, could you please tell whether this leads to memory leak? I have a listview whose width is bound to this function`function calcWidth(){
    var w = 0;
    for(var i in list.contentItem.children) {
        var child = list.contentItem.children[i];
        w+=child.width;
    }
    return w
}
`

Comment: Well, I don't think that will lead to memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution, which is quite ugly, is to edit the `qmldir` file from `gcc/qml/QtQuick/Controls` and add the following line:

> TreeView 1.4 TreeView.qml

As a result for me :

```
module QtQuick.Controls
plugin qtquickcontrolsplugin
classname QtQuickControlsPlugin
typeinfo plugins.qmltypes
designersupported
depends QtQuick.Window 2.2 
TreeView 1.4 TreeView.qml
```

You can do so for each QML file which is in the `QtQuick/Controls` directory.

In this way, `TreeView` and all other QML types you will add to this file will be recognized by QtCreator.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html